# Delete all the rows for which ctid are fetched

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I need to delete all the rows for which the ctid's are fetched using the join query

The Query that I use to fetch the multiple rows

Each row return 4 ctid's.

I need to delete all the 4 rows from the table for each row

My query to fetch ctid is ==>

```
select 
  t1.ctid, 
  t2.ctid, 
  t3.ctid, 
  t4.ctid 
from 
  auditrtailreference t1
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t2 
  on t2.sourceid = t1.destinationid 
  AND t2.event ='80' 
  AND t2.innodename like '%_SFTP'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t3 
  on t3.sourceid = t2.destinationid 
  AND t3.event ='68'
LEFT JOIN auditrtailreference t4 
  on t4.sourceid = t1.destinationid 
  AND t4.event ='73'
where t1.event ='67' 
  and t1.innodename like '%_SFTP' 
  and t3.destinationid like '%' 
  and t1.outtime >= '2014/09/10 00:00' 
  and t1.outtime <= '2014/09/11 15:24' 
  AND t3.outnodename like '%init_Dist' 
  AND t3.destinationid like '%my%'
```

But since each row returns 4 columns I cannot use in clause

please help me over this

Regards

Khanjarrr

Comment: NOTE: using t3.xxx in the `WHERE` clause effictively changes your `LEFT JOIN` into a plain `JOIN`.

Comment: Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/fe067/10), I think this is what you want. I didn't use ctid though as I'm not sure how it's supposed to be used, but the query should be easy to modify. If it is what you want I'll post it as an answer.